# Facet API pretty paths in combination with solr search form

Tags: uri, search, panels

I'm building a website with the panopoly distribution in Drupal 7. One of the client requests is a faceted search page combined with a search box to search on specific keywords and the possibility to sort on date and name.

To build this I used the following modules:

- apachesolr
- apachesolr_sorts
- apachesolr_panels

After configuring everything I got this search page working (without clean url's)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RZAn.png

[image: solution with no clean url's]

To enable clean url's I used the following module:

- facetapi_pretty_paths

Now the search box always uses the first argument in the url, after I enable the pretty paths module the first argument in the url is the active filter (taxonomy field name in combination with the taxonomy term name).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERU2I.png

[image: solution with clean url's]

What would be the best approach to use the search box in combination with the facets and pretty paths (and the sorting option)?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to avoid this issue which depend on module what you use.

1) If Search API module is used. (It was taken from https://www.drupal.org/node/2625298)

```
function hook_search_api_query_alter(SearchApiQueryInterface $query) {
    $original_keys = $query->getOriginalKeys();
    if ($original_keys == 'field_facet_filter')) {
        $query->keys(NULL);
    }
}
```

2) If Apache Solr Search module is use

```
function hook_apachesolr_query_prepare(DrupalSolrQueryInterface $query) {
  ‌‌if ($query->getParam('q') == 'field_facet_filter') {
    $query->removeParam('q');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use search_api, the search term is put into a get parameter rather than as a path argument. this fixes the problem.

i would believe though, that people have also found a solution for the apachesolr module suite.